# Is there a difference between a Markov Kernel and a Transition Kernel?

Tags: sampling, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

I have been reading some literature on particle filters and it seems that the definition of a Markov Kernel and a Transition Kernel seem to be the same. However, I was wondering if these two terms when used in literature are the same thing. Does anyone know the parlance here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(x,A)$ is a ***Markov*** kernel ($x \in X$ and $A \in \mathcal{B}(X)$) if

1. for each $A$, $P(\cdot,A)$ is non-negative and measurable, and
2. for each $x$, $P(x,\cdot)$ is a probability measure.

When people drop the "Markov" part, I take it to mean either

1. we're losing non-negativity when considering $P$ as a function in the first argument, or
2. It's a measure in the second argument, but not necessarily a probability  measure (e.g. $P(x,X) \le 1$ or $P(x,X) > 1$).

Comment: When you mention the dropping of the Markov part, do you mean a transition kernel or just a kernel by itself?

Comment: @user321627 stochastic/Markov/transition all mean the same thing to me. When people say Kernel by itself, they might mean the general way. And this all depends on the context; it wouldn't be unlikely that someone just says kernel when they are talking about a Markov chain

Comment: @user321627 if youre looking at pfilters im pretty certain you mean Markov/transition kernel

Comment: Markov is commonly associated with a "memoryless" property (e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/markov-process/info))